# p-fullCalendar inside p-dialog not showing events when resize browser

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I have a p-fullCalendar inside p-dialog. When I open dialog, the fullcalendar show the events, also if I close the dialog and open again. 
But, if I close dialog and then resize window browser, and open dialog, the full calendar shows empty.
Here is the code:

```
<p-dialog header="title" [(visible)]="showCalendar" (onHide)="closeDialog()" [style]="{width: '50vw'}">

                        <p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options">

                        </p-fullCalendar>
                        <p-footer>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="closeDialog()">Close</button>
                        </p-footer>
                    </p-dialog> 
this.events = [
            {
                title: 'Pepe',
                start: '2020-04-01',
            },
            {
                title: 'Juan',
                start: '2020-04-07',
                end: '2020-04-10',
            },
            {
                title: 'Jose',
                start: '2020-04-07',
                end: '2020-04-10',
            },
            {
                title: 'Luis',
                start: '2020-04-09T16:00:00',
            },
            {
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2020-04-16T16:00:00',
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2020-04-11',
                end: '2020-04-13',
            },
        ]
        this.options = {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: '',
            },
            editable: false,
        }
```

Comment: Can you mention code of `closeDialog() ` handler?

Comment: closeDialog() {
  this.showCalendar= false

 }